# is there a way to respond to a GET\POST request in a later time?

Tags: node.js, express, response

using Express (NodeJS), is there a way to save the details of a request so that the response will be done in a later time? (basically, leaving the request hangin for the response).
without using setTimeout() or sleep or any other delay.

for example if this is my function:

```
function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    setTimeout(function() {
        res.json(data);
    }, 3000);
}
```

is it possible to use (req, res) objects outside that function scope?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  I mean, there's all kinds of reasons to defer processing, but leaving the HTTP response hanging is going to have negative impacts on your application's scalability and your user experience.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do it via `setTimeout`

```
function(req, res) {
    var data = req.body;
    setTimeout(function() {
        res.json(data);
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: using (req, res) objects outside of this function scope.

Comment: is it possible to use req, res objects outside that function scope?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way, you can use expressjs response.setTimeOut function for implemention.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.setTimeout(5000, () => {
    res.send("hello");
  });
});

app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("app is listening on port 4000");
});
```